# How do I combine different data from different documents?

Tags: python, taxonomy

I'm trying to combine data from different files, so that for each item - OTU number and its assigned species from one document can be combined with that OTUs sequence in another document, where OTU number is in one line, and sequence in the next line.

I have managed to append the data I need from the first document, but I can't append anything from the second document for the same OTU at all.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
tax_file=open("C:\\Users\\Line\\Documents\\regnorme\\Bioinformatic\\New_folder1\\tax_new\\16s_tree\\16s_tree5\\taxonomy_tree5.txt")

fasta_file=open("C:\\Users\\Line\\Documents\\regnorme\\Bioinformatic\\New_folder1\\tax_new\\16s_tree\\16s_tree5\\fasta_tree5.2.txt")

OTUs_in_shared=('Otu0001', ... other otus here ...., 'Otu2381')

Vermi_OTUs = []
for line in tax_file:
if line.startswith("Otu"):
    if line.split()[0] in OTUs_in_shared:
        if line.split()[7].startswith("Verminephrobacter"):
            OTU={'OTUnr':(line.split()[0]), 'Family':(line.split()[6]), 
'Genera':(line.split()[7])}
            Vermi_OTUs.append(OTU)

for line in Vermi_OTUs:
    for line in fasta_file:
        if 'OTUnr' in line.split():
            if 'sequence' not in OTU:
                OTU['sequence']=[]
        OTU['sequence'].append(line.split()[0])
print(Vermi_OTUs)
```

Comment: attach your code as text not an image

Comment: thanks, I tried adding my code, however, i couldn't add the file-open codes, bout they're in the document and seem to be working